# How to dynamically build and link boost::regex with hidden inlines?

Tags: c++, macos, shared-libraries, inline, clang

As part of my (OSX) project, I am building boost::regex as a dynamic library. When I build and link without -fvisibility-***inlines***-hidden, everything works as expected.

To work around a bug in another external dependency, I need to turn this compiler switch on, however. Doing so results in lots of linker errors like this one

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, 
  std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<
  char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, 
  boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::find()", referenced from:
      bool boost::regex_search<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, 
  std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<
  char const*, std::string> > >, char, boost::regex_traits<char, 
  boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, 
  std::string>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, 
  boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, 
  std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, 
  std::string> > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, 
  boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags,
  __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>) in Regex.o
```

when I try to link boost to my project (the file "Regex.o" is part of the boost dylib). As I understand [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Conceptual/CppRuntimeEnv/Articles/SymbolVisibility.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001670-98807), limiting inline visibility should just cause every dynamic lib to get its own instance of the inlined function, but should never cause linker errors.

It seems there is a related [compiler bug for virtual methods](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12255), but neither `perl_matcher::find()` nor `regex_search()` are virtual methods.

Any suggestions/ideas?

```
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is a compiler bug in clang 3.1. Boost declares the template inline member function `perl_matcher<...>::find()` (and others) as `external`; only the instance linked into the boost dylib is not marked as external. Because it is inline, clang 3.1 hides this instance from the dylib's export table with `-fvisibility-inlines-hidden`.

It seems that this bug is fixed in the current trunk of clang (3.2.x). Until then, defining `BOOST_REGEX_NO_EXTERNAL_TEMPLATES` works around this bug (if it is acceptable to possibly have multiple instances of these inline functions in your binary). Otherwise, patching boost::regex to explicitly export the symbols defined in `boost/regex/v4/instances.hpp` using `__attribute__ ((visibility("default")))` when `BOOST_REGEX_INSTANTIATE` is defined should also do the job (see the `#define template` hack at the top of `instances.hpp`).